# Using Asp.Net Core, how can I open a view as a new browser tab, and then close it again later

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

While I want to avoid Pop-ups (due to pop-up blockers and the like), I do want a certain link when clicked to open up the associated View in a new browser tab. But then within that view (just a form with some user elements and a submit button), when it's submitted, I need to have it then close the new tab (essentially returning control to the original tab).

I thought I had it solved with adding target="_blank" to the  tag in question, and at the end of the controller force it to redirect to a CloseTab view that was nothing more than javascript to call window.close();

Unfortunately, while opening the new tab works, when it tries to close the tab after the submit is complete, it fails with "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them"

How can I close the tab that I opened with the target _blank? Or should I be using some different method (not a popup, so window.open is out) to open the view in a new tab?

My code is below:

In the calling view (the  tag mentioned before):

```
<a asp-controller="TimePunches" asp-action="PunchIn" target="_blank">Punch In</a>
```

PunchIn.cshtml:

```
@model TimePunchViewModel

<form asp-action="PunchIn">
    @{ 
        // TODO: user editable fields go here
    }

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

TimePunchController.cs:

```
public IActionResult PunchIn()
{
    var model = new TimePunchViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PunchIn(TimePunchViewModel model)
{
// TODO: save based on model

// close the tab
    return View("CloseTab");
}
```

CloseTab.cshtml:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax submit the form and close window in the success callback function.

PunchIn.cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="PunchIn" method="post">
    @{ 
        // TODO: user editable fields go here
    }
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Scripts:

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                window.close();
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PunchIn(TimePunchViewModel model)
{
    // TODO: save based on model

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I have it working, but now I've run into another problem - if I'm on that page/view and I submit changes and I need to keep the page up (such as showing validation errors or filtering the data), it still is closing the tab. How do I update this logic so I can avoid that?